# How to find number of columns in row for array in TCL

Tags: arrays, tcl

I have different number of columns for my array called `cb_node`. To post-process this data, The requirement is to exactly know the number of columns in each row.

The array looks like following.

```
cb_node(1,1) value
cb_node(1,2) value
...
cb_node(1,256) value

cb_node(2,1) value
....
cb_node(2,56) value
```

and so on..
each row in array has different number of columns. `value` is just example, it's different for key in array.

The set of commands in TCL are only `array get cb_node` and `array size cb_node` which does not give the row and column number for each row.

How we can do that in TCL ?

Comment: You'd be better off using a 2-d dict instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `1` in the key indicates the row number, then you could perhaps use something like this:

```
set rowNum 1
set noOfColumns [llength [array names cb_node $rowNum,*]]
```

Comment: Of course, you can use a loop and iterate on the row numbers while using the above to get the number of columns in each row (you will have to stop/break when the number of columns reaches 0)

Comment: Hi Jerry, array names has this special feature ..great !!

Comment: @SemiCode `array names` just gets all the keys in an array, and you can supply a glob pattern to narrow down the keys you want to get.

Answer (score 1):

```
set count {}
foreach key [array names cb_node] {
    lassign [split $key ,] row col
    dict incr count $row
}
dict for {row n} $count {
    puts "row $row has $n cols"
}
```

```
row 2 has 56 cols
row 1 has 256 cols
```

Comment: Hi Glenn, What's actually happening in "dict incr count $row" ?  not able to get on on internet with example :(

Comment: Hmm, I didn't initialize the variable: I updated my answer. `can't read "count": no such variable` would indicate your `cb_node` array is empty.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know how many rows or columns you have, but you know there's no skipped rows, you can loop as long as [`info exists`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/info.htm#M14) is true:

```
#!/usr/bin/env tclsh

array set cb_node {1,1 a 1,2 b 1,3 c 2,1 d 3,1 e 3,2 f}

for {set row 1} {[info exists cb_node($row,1)]} {incr row} {
    for {set col 1} {[info exists cb_node($row,$col)]} {incr col} {
        puts "cb_node($row,$col) = $cb_node($row,$col)"
    }
}
```

this will print out

```
cb_node(1,1) = a
cb_node(1,2) = b
cb_node(1,3) = c
cb_node(2,1) = d
cb_node(3,1) = e
cb_node(3,2) = f
```